# RStudio Environment TAB missing blanks on strings. Is this a BUG?

Tags: rstudio

On RStudio console, I enter:

```
S = "a     b"
```

then, on environment TAB, I see S = "a b"
The spaces have collapsed to only one space!?

Is this a BUG ?
Very annoying this behaviour

Comment: By default, RStudio changes tabs to 2 spaces. If you wish to change this behaviour, go to Tools -> Global Options. In the window, select "Code" on the left hand side, and uncheck "Insert Spaces for tab".

Comment: Hey, there's no tabs involved here! I inserted only blanks, and I'm referring to the "ENVIRONMENT TAB" of the IDE